# when run it gives error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'members'

Tags: python-3.x, discord

this is my code

```
for member in guildsd.members:
    if author == bot.user:#bot luôn luôn đặt vị trí member của bot ở đầu tiên vậy nên code bot.user sẽ luôn bằng bot của bạn
        return
    if 'member' in content:
        await say(member)
    if 'test' in content:
```

Comment: the error means `guildsd1` object is `None`

Answer (score 0):

The codes performed in a DM channel, `guild` is `None` hear.
These can be a good alternative:

1. use channel members:

```py
channel = ctx.channel


for member in channel.members:
    ...
```

2. use a check:

```py
# ---------- for commands ----------
@guild_only() # from discord.ext.commands
@command()
async def my_command(ctx):
    ctx.guilds # Always is Guild object

# ---------- for events ----------
@client.event
async def on_<event>(..., channel, ...):
    ...
    is not isinstanse(channel, DMChannel):
        ... # channel is on a guild
    else:
        ... # this is DMChannel or GroupChannel
```